# CCAvenue Error after redirecting to Payment Gateway - Error Code: 109

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am getting the following error after redirection to payment gateway.
Have anybody seen this or possibly point out the reason for this error code ?

**CCAvenue Transaction Error Page
Error Code:  109
Error Description:  Internal+error+while+processing**

Thanks

Comment: As far as i saw, CCAvenue changed their system and API recently. Are you using latest codes?